# (KOTLIN) Requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-pendingintent

In every new message that comes to my account, the application restarts itself. Then it gives this error.I tried to find the solution but failed.I write the error code on the bottom line.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.edusoft.teacher.myeducare, PID: 7367
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.edusoft.teacher.myeducare: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4438)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:265)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2114)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8168)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1037)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.edusoft.teacher.myeducare: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
        at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:378)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:648)
        at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:635)
        at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.getNewActionPendingIntent(GenerateNotification.java:195)
        at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.createGenericPendingIntentsForNotif(GenerateNotification.java:404)
        at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.showNotification(GenerateNotification.java:388)
        at com.onesignal.GenerateNotification.fromJsonPayload(GenerateNotification.java:116)
        at com.onesignal.NotificationBundleProcessor.ProcessJobForDisplay(NotificationBundleProcessor.java:115)
        at com.onesignal.NotificationBundleProcessor.ProcessFromGCMIntentService(NotificationBundleProcessor.java:98)
        at com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver.startGCMService(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:138)
        at com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver.processOrderBroadcast(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:129)
        at com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GcmBroadcastReceiver.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4425)
            ... 9 more
```

i found this code but either i did not use it correctly or it does not work properly

```
val updatedPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
   applicationContext,
   NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE,
   updatedIntent,
   PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT // setting the mutability flag 
)
```

Comment: Are you somehow providing that `PendingIntent` to OneSignal? This crash is coming from OneSignal and its receipt of a FCM message, based on the stack trace. My guess is that you need to update your OneSignal SDK or otherwise talk to them about this crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app targets Android 12, you must specify the mutability of each PendingIntent object that your app creates. This additional requirement improves your app's security.

`PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);`

we’re constructing a standard type of Intent that will open our app, and then simply wrapping that in a PendingIntent before adding it to our notification.In this case, since we have an exact action we know we want to perform, we construct a PendingIntent that cannot be modified by the app we pass it to by utilizing a flag called FLAG_IMMUTABLE.

This change is must required if you are targeting Android S+ and you have integrate FCM in you app.

You can check [this blog](https://medium.com/walmartglobaltech/migrating-a-1m-users-app-to-android-12-challenges-solutions-cfc00b0e36b3) if you plan to migrate your app compatible with Android 12.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
val updatedPendingIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    } else {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

Comment: where exactly should I write this? Mainactivity? Because it has the same situation on the home page i have the same problem on the messageFragment site

Comment: you should be creating one notification class which is extending FirebaseMessagingService . in that class you must be building notification which has NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId).setContentIntent(updatedPendingIntent)

Answer (score 0):

In your log showing error,
*

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.edusoft.teacher.myeducare: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

Android application targets to 31 which has reported more crashes (only Android OS 12 users) in Firebase Messaging (PendingIntent) or in **Notification function**. When Application is in Pause/Background state on Notification Receive its crashing.

In addition , you may need to increase the version of implementation `"androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.5.0"` to the latest update

[Reference link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#FLAG_MUTABLE)

```
 val updatedPendingIntent = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE, updatedIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
    } else {
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
            applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_REQUEST_CODE, updatedIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
        )
    }
```

Comment: Please explain in detail how this ties into the stack trace shown in the question.

Comment: Whenever a message comes to my application, it restarts iteslf. It does not matter which fragment it is in. I started getting this problem after i made SDK version 31. I dont know how to use PendingIntent anywhere.